# Bootstrap fields in a column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering what I have done wrong here: http://www.bootply.com/bURS2tSeSU

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Contact Us</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control input-md">
  <span class="help-block">help</span>  
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message">default text</textarea>
</div>
    <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
   </fieldset>
</form>
</div>

 </div> 
   </div>
```

My panel-body should have padding but instead it seems like the padding isn't taking effect for the form fields. Can anyone tell me why this might be happening and how I can get my fields to sit within the panel-body and not right up to the edges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you stuck everything into a column. Each component in a column take up equal width (specified by you as `col-md-4`). I replaced your column with a row, and wrapped everything by a container (which you *always* need to do).

**Code**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Contact Us</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <fieldset>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control input-md"> <span class="help-block">help</span> 
                </div>
                <!-- Textarea -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message">default text</textarea>
                </div>
                <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/6OGipd3FWD)

Comment: But how does it work if I only want the contact form to take up 1/3 of the page, I have to stick it in a column. In this respect how do I do that?

Comment: Yes, then put the whole panel inside a column. @Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `form-group`. According to bootstrap documentation:

> Use Bootstrap's predefined grid classes to align labels and groups of form controls in a horizontal layout by adding `.form-horizontal` to the form. Doing so changes `.form-groups` to behave as grid rows, so no need for `.row`.

But in turn this means, that you will have to add columns for your input fields:

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Contact Us</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <fieldset>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control input-md"> <span class="help-block">help</span> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Textarea -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message">default text</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- submit button -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

See here http://www.bootply.com/rSLgYayGaO